# Publish "commented on" story to my page's Facebook wall

Tags: php, facebook

I have FB comments plugins for each page on my site.  I have an FB app for my site, and a page on FB.

I would like to comment on a particular page on my site using the PHP SDK (or other server-side means) in such a way that a "xxx commented on yyy" story appears in my page's feed, i.e. I would like to comment on my site /as/ my page, and have that comment appear in my page's feed.

I am able (after much suffering) to post a comment as my page, e.g.

`curl -F access_token=... -F message=test -F id=http://.... -F http://graph.facebook.com/comments`

But using that method there is no story on my page's feed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand, you want your comments as your website's page app to show up on your personal newsfeed when you make a comment as your page.

I would submit this to facebook because it seems like a shortcoming of their API.  I'm pretty sure there is no real way to make your page's comments show up on your feed like as though they were your own.

Sorry

Comment: Even simpler than that -- I would like comments made as my page to appear on my page's feed! This happens when I comment manually via the plugin, but not when I comment using the PHP SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - bug posted at http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=17447.